# ADB touchevent does not work dependent on computer

Tags: android, automation, adb

I have a few questions on ADB.

I try to run the following batch file:

```
adb wait-for-devices
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 53 67 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 54 768
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 48 40
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 50 4
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 57 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 0 2 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 53 67
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 54 768
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 48 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 50 4
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 57 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 0 2 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event9 0 0 0

adb shell input keyevent 8
adb shell input keyevent 9
adb shell input keyevent 10
adb shell input keyevent 11
adb shell input keyevent 12

adb shell input keyevent 5
```

- first part deals with getting to the dialer via touchevents 
  (I did not find a keyevent for this)
- second part types 1,2,3,4,5 via keyevents
- third part presses the call button via keyevent

If I run this script with the connected cellphone on my computer here, the touchevents
are replayed correctly and 12345 is called.
If I connect it to a different PC, the first part does not bring me to the dial screen
for some reason?

What could be the reason, that my code runs on one computer and not on the other?

Is there another way to emulate finger sweeps except for touchevents?

**EDIT**:

It seems, that the connection is a little slow on the pc, where it works not as good.
ADB versions are the same and actually I was able to make the behavior run by changing the script.

Now I see, that when I create touchevents e.g. for a sweeping action.
These are many events.
When I then input them one by one using the command adb shell sendevent as above.
I can observe on the cellphone, that the sweeping is really really slow.
Is there a way somehow to pipe the commands directly into adb such, that
the reaction is as fast as with a normal finger sweep?

Comment: Touch event codes and channel (device file) assignments are not portable between phones and android versions as they include implementation-specific detail.  As for why it would work or not with the same phone but a different host PC, there could be oddities in the adb installation or host shell being used to launch adb.  Try single quoting the command passed to the adb shell, ie adb shell 'sendevent /dev/input/event9 3 53 67'

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Using the single quote results in, that it does not work at all anymore. Can you be clearer for the first part about the touchevent codes and channel? I use the same phone.Both are windows host computer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Proceeding as [shell/ batch scripting to direct commands to adb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474318/shell-batch-scripting-to-direct-commands-to-adb-shell/13050815#13050815)
solved the problem.

The actual problem was, that calling the adb shell for each command
takes a lot of time.

This results in lagged execution and conflicts occur because of this timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to dial a number you can always use `service call phone 2 s16 "12345"`

Answer (score 1):

Also in the recent Android versions you can use `input tap` and `input swipe` commands

```
usage: input ...
       input text <string>
       input keyevent <key code number or name>
       input tap <x> <y>
       input swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2>
```