# Send multiple same keyevents to the adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

How can you send multiple key events to the adb shell of the same key? For example, you can issue one 'delete' key event (#67) like this:

```
adb shell input keyevent 67
```

But is there something like this (note: this won't work)?

```
adb shell input keyevent 67 67
```

Comment: can you use 2 commands? 
adb shell input keyevent 67
adb shell input keyevent 67
?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use

```
adb shell "input keyevent 67 && input keyevent 67"
```

If you need to write large scripts, you can also try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474318/shell-batch-scripting-to-direct-commands-to-adb-shell).

Comment: This works. Unfortunately, speed wise, it is the same as entering `adb shell input keyevent 67` twice. I was hoping that maybe it would be as fast as when you do `adb shell input text 'HE'` versus having two lines of code: `adb shell input text 'H'` and `adb shell input text 'E'`.

Comment: I think it is more suitable for combinations

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about speed, I suggest using the *sendevent* command to send an event. I've found it to be significantly faster especially when it comes to simulating a tap.

**Example**

```
sendevent /dev/input/event18 1 67 1 // send key down event 67
sendevent /dev/input/event18 0 0 0  // end of report
sendevent /dev/input/event18 1 67 0 // send key up event 67
sendevent /dev/input/event18 0 0 0  // end of report
```

**SYNTAX**

```
sendevent <device> <type> <code> <value>
```

**NOTE**

This is sending events at a low level, which can give a lot of control and also flexibility to make it efficient by sending the exact events you are interested in. A big drawback, in my opinion, is the fact that you'll have to determine the device on your own (probably by using *getevent* command and manually figuring it out) The device */dev/input/event18* is just an example I used from my phone, this isn't constant.

For reference to valid arguments, you can see the header file. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/kernel-headers/+/8bc979c0f7b0b30b579b38712a091e7d2037c77e/original/uapi/linux/input.h

Comment: sendevent: /dev/input/event0: Permission denied

In [189]: !C:\QGB\software\scrcpy-win64\adb.exe shell "sendevent /dev/input/event4 1 67 1 "
sendevent: /dev/input/event4: Permission denied