# ADB Accessibility Focus Change

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I would like to know how to make the ADB adjust the accessibility focus while Talkback is on. I have tried:

```
adb shell input trackball roll 0 1
adb shell input [stylusdpad|keyboard|mouse|touchpad|gamepad|touchnavigation|joystick|touchscreen|stylus|trackball] swipe 180 780 540 780
adb shell input keyboard keyevent KEYCODE_TAB
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT
adb shell "input keyevent KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT & input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT"
```

I have also tried recording events using `adb shell getevent` and playing them back without success.

But I always have to physically swipe the screen (i.e. **an ADB swipe does not work**) to get the accessibility focus to change. Is there a way to do this with accessibility, just a next and previous movement?

I have found this [article by Google](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6110948?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdefault-keymap):

> **Navigation**
>
> - Move to next item: Alt + Right arrow
>   Note: In continuous reading mode, this shortcut fast-forwards through the text.
> - Move to previous item: Alt + Left arrow
>   Note: In continuous reading mode, this shortcut rewinds the text.

Which means I just need to send multiple key presses at once, right? I tried this, [based on another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30272187/932052):

```
device="/dev/input/event3"
ALT_KEY=57#18 #KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT
LEFT_KEY=21#37 #KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT
RIGHT_KEY=22#39 #KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT

device="/dev/input/event0"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0 & sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event1"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0 & sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event2"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0 & sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event3"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0 & sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 & sendevent $device 0 0 0"

device="/dev/input/event0"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event1"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event2"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event3"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"

device="/dev/input/event0"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event1"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event2"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
device="/dev/input/event3"
adb shell "sendevent $device 1 $ALT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 1 $RIGHT_KEY 1 && sendevent $device 0 0 0"
```

(even though I know `device0` is actually the keyboard device, I wanted to try them all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer here is going to be as succinct as possible. My full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/qbalsdon/accessibility_broadcast_dev).

As far as I am aware, a developer cannot perform an accessibility action via ADB, they would have to create an [Accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service) in order to [act on behalf of an Accessibility user](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#act-for-users) and create a [Broadcast Receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) so that it can take input via the ADB. This is two thirds of the answer, requiring one more component as developers <s>cannot activate accessibility services via the ADB! This has to be done manually **each time accessibility is toggled** or through [**accessibility shortcuts**](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7650693?hl=en) - of which there can be only one.</s> **EDIT** I figured this bit out as well :)

#### Accessibility Service

The developer documentation provides a mechanism for an [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service):

> An accessibility service is an application that provides user interface enhancements to assist users with disabilities, or who may temporarily be unable to fully interact with a device. For example, users who are driving, taking care of a young child or attending a very loud party might need additional or alternative interface feedback.

I followed the [Google Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service) to construct a service that could take actions on the part of a user. Here is a snippet from the service, for swiping left and right (user navigation):

```
    fun swipeHorizontal(leftToRight: Boolean) {
        val swipePath = Path()
        if (leftToRight) {
            swipePath.moveTo(halfWidth - quarterWidth, halfHeight)
            swipePath.lineTo(halfWidth + quarterWidth, halfHeight)
        } else {
            swipePath.moveTo(halfWidth + quarterWidth, halfHeight)
            swipePath.lineTo(halfWidth - quarterWidth, halfHeight)
        }
        val gestureBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        gestureBuilder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 500))
        dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), GestureResultCallback(baseContext), null)
    }
```

#### Broadcast receiver.

It's important to note that the Receiver is registered when the service is enabled:

```
    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(ACCESSIBILITY_CONTROL_BROADCAST_ACTION)

            priority = 100

            registerReceiver(accessibilityActionReceiver, this)           
        }
   // REMEMBER TO DEREGISTER!
```

Then the receiver can respond to intents and invoke the service:

```
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        require(intent != null) { "Intent is required" }
        val serviceReference = //get a reference to the service somehow

        intent.getStringExtra(ACCESSIBILITY_ACTION)?.let {
            serviceReference.apply {
                when (it) {
                    ACTION_NEXT -> swipeHorizontal(true)
                    ACTION_PREV -> swipeHorizontal(false)
                    //...
```

example usage on the adb:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.balsdon.talkback.accessibility -e ACTION "ACTION_PREV"
```

**EDIT**

#### Starting the service via adb:

Thanks to [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225907/grant-permissions-to-a-service-launched-with-adb#comment303377_231062)

```
TALKBACK="com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService"
ALLYDEV="com.balsdon.accessibilityBroadcastService/.AccessibilityBroadcastService"
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services $TALKBACK:$ALLYDEV
```

#### Accessibility shortcut

** EDIT: NO LONGER NEEDED BUT I'LL LEAVE IT HERE ANYWAY **

Possibly the most annoying thing is that every time accessibility is toggled, the service is turned off. So I added my [service as a shortcut](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7650693?hl=en) with the VOLUME_UP and VOLUME_DOWN keys pressed. [Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37473751/932052).

```
  INPUT_DEVICE="/dev/input/event1" # VOLUME KEYS EVENT FILE
  VOLUME_DOWN=114 #0x0072
  VOLUME_UP=115   #0x0073
  BLANK_EVENT="sendevent $INPUT_DEVICE 0 0 0"

  INST_DN="sendevent $INPUT_DEVICE 1 $VOLUME_DOWN 1 && $BLANK_EVENT && sendevent $INPUT_DEVICE 1 $VOLUME_UP 1 && $BLANK_EVENT"
  INST_UP="sendevent $INPUT_DEVICE 1 $VOLUME_DOWN 0 && $BLANK_EVENT && sendevent $INPUT_DEVICE 1 $VOLUME_UP 0 && $BLANK_EVENT"
  adb shell "$INST_DN"
  sleep 3
  adb shell "$INST_UP"
```

I already have a script for [toggling accessibility on/off](https://github.com/qbalsdon/talos/blob/main/scripts/talkback), so I just tacked this on top of that and I get my service running every time.

**EDIT 2**

I put an issue on [AOSP](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185546073) regarding the fact that a developer needs to write a "service that swipes" as opposed to a "service that navigates". This is problematic as the gestures can be modified and then my system will not behave as expected. Instead I should be able to call the particular action I want to do `NAVIGATE TO NEXT ELEMENT` or `NAVIGATE TO PREVIOUS ELEMENT` as opposed to "SWIPE RIGHT" and "SWIPE LEFT" - having read the WCAG guidelines I do not believe that this is violating the principles.