# Is it possible to produce continuous swipe action on the touchscreen, with adb, on Android?

Tags: android, adb, swipe, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to reproduce swipe action, with the help of adb. 
Currently, this code works (for swipe)

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe 530 1420 530 1120
adb shell input touchscreen swipe 530 1120 830 1120
```

which is

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe x1,y1, x2,y2
```

but they are two discontinuous swipes.. Its equivalent to doing the first swipe, take ur hand off the screen and do the second swipe and so on..

I would like to achieve this as a single swipe.. 
Like, imagine a game where theres hot fire underneath and you have to drag [om-nom](http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/om-nom.png) across various obstacles without taking your finger off [om-nom](http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/om-nom.png).. with the above mentioned adb swipe, poor [om-nom](http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/om-nom.png) would fall into the fire and become [roasted-om-nom](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130805143948/cuttherope/images/7/77/Om_nom.png). :(

something like

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe [(x1,y1, x2,y2), (x3,y3, x4,y4)...(xn-1,yn-1, xn,yn)]
```

if not adb, any other alternative?

Comment: with adb? can you tell why?

Comment: @pskink because I would like to do something without physically touching the phone.. just an experiment.

Comment: Very interesting as Im trying the same, doing the screen unlock via ADB, but as @Ocelot I get 3 discontinous swipes

Comment: @CorvenDallas you can use [unlock.sh](https://github.com/mattwilson1024/android-pattern-unlock/blob/master/unlock.sh) script for that. To get the proper coords just use `screencap` to get a screenshot of your phone lockscreen.

Comment: this answer may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73821035/236465

Answer (score 14):

You can do it in ADB. Use getevent to record your manual input with:

```
adb shell getevent
```

Or to record a specific device:

```
adb shell getevent /dev/input/eventx
```

Then simuate recorded input with:

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/eventx
```

Comment: Great suggestion.. trying it now.. already able to simulate hardware buttons :) .. will up-vote u if I get the desired output..

Comment: @Ocelot, Have you tried doing it [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363526/fire-a-pinch-in-out-command-to-android-phone-using-adb/25629952#25629952) ?. Using `getevent` and `setevent`, I was able to automate Actions/Taps.

Comment: I tried what HelgaM suggested but that doesn't seem to work on the lock screen. I wanna simulate Pattern unlock.

Comment: @Ocelot see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500567/is-it-possible-to-produce-continuous-swipe-action-on-the-touchscreen-with-adb#comment58804317_25500567).

Answer (score 5):

```
adb shell  "input touchscreen swipe 126 459 413 472 & input command touchscreen swipe 413 472 407 769"
```

You must run inside android device ***input*** command, for continue swap add **&** between ***input*** command, example below:

```
adb shell "
   input touchscreen swipe 126 459 413 472 1000 & \ # 1th line 
   input touchscreen swipe 413 472 72  776 1000 & \ # 2th line
   input touchscreen swipe 72  776 407 769 1000 | echo done # 3th line" 


126 459   =   302 446   =   413 472
===================================
112 599   =   268 613   =   470 612
===================================
72  776   =   263 802   =   407 769

input touchscreen swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
```

But need to make pausing or delaying (sleep,wait) between command's in order for more precise swipe.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Well sorry , my English it's so bad but surely in future i will try to comment my answers

Comment: There is an [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50358620/edit) at the bottom of your post. You can use that to expand upon your answer.

Comment: This solution will result in 3 swipes being executed at the same time, not continuously. There is no way a sleep command can help.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for a pixel 6 pro. Adjust the 3rd parameter in your adb shell command according to your screen size. A few trial and errors should give you the right number.
The below would do a right swipe 100 times.

```
for i in {1..100}
do
adb shell  "input touchscreen swipe 126 459 913 472"
done
```

Paste the code block as is in your terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately on Xiaomi Poco 5X : `java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission`. However on a Samsung A51 it works!

Answer (score 1):

If your use case allows for slow swipe like within 2000ms, then the swipe is almost like a drag.

`shell input touchscreen swipe x1,y1, x2,y2 [duration]`

Answer (score -2):

This works

`$adb shell input touchscreen swipe x1 y1 & adb shell input touchescreen x2 y2 & adb shell input touchescreen x3 y3`

Answer (score -4):

I think this will be a good option

```
for i in {1..5}; do adb shell input touchscreen swipe 530 1420 530 1120; adb shell input touchscreen swipe 530 1120 830 1120; done
```