# iOS equivalent of android adb unlock

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, appium, appium-ios

I am currently working with Appium and a range of mobile devices remotely (imagine a bunch of pcs/macs in a room offsite which I have remote access to with each device plugged in via usb cable). **I can handle almost everything in Appium apart from it seems unlocking the device**.

To get around this on android I followed the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072501/how-to-unlock-android-phone-through-adb#answer-29072625) and it worked great using the adb command line.

Is there a way to do the same kind of **unlock for iOS**?

Comment: Unlock how? When the phone is off and asleep you want to unlock it? Or unlock from a network? Either way... neither of them are possible on iOS.

Comment: So the phone (usually an iPhone 5S running iOS 11.3) is plugged into the mac but is currently asleep. I want to unlock it so that Appium can run it's tests.

Edit:: In settings it's been told to never sleep but sometimes decides to lock itself.

Comment: The xcode message in _Devices and Simulators_ says "Xcode will continue when iPhone 5S is unlocked".

Comment: That's what happens in Xcode too. The ability to unlock in this case would bypass any security on the phone. I don't think there is a way... and I don't think Apple would ever create a way to bypass that.

Comment: Also... you shouldn't be running tests on device. Tests should be run on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other Q&A. We are running acceptance tests on a range of devices to test bluetooth and camera (scanning) functionality for the product we sell.