# ADB: drag vs. swipe / manual drag via events

Tags: android, adb

I want to control an Android device programmatically via ADB.

Since I have to scroll a list, I tried to scroll via a command like:

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe 935 500 789 500 1000
```

This works, but the problem is that Android adds a fling/rubber band effect. So when the swipe is done it still scrolls a bit further. But I need to scoll pixel-perfect so this approach doesn't work in the way I need it. Even when I increase the swipe duration to 3000ms it scrolls for some more pixels.

Is there maybe an easy trick to tell ADB/my device 'swipe but hold down the finger after moving for ~500ms before releasing the finger in order to prevent the fling effect'?

What I also tried is to control the events manually.
Therefore I ran `adb getevent`, performed a swipe on the device and collected the output:

```
[...]
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0035 000000fb
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 0000000a
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0035 000000fa
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 0000000b
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0036 000001b6
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 0000000c
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0035 000000f9
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 0000000d
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0035 000000f8
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 0000000e
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0035 000000f7
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 0000000f
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0030 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0039 ffffffff
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event6: 0003 002f 0000000c
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0039 0000000c
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0035 000000f7
/dev/input/event6: 0003 0036 000001b6
/dev/input/event6: 0000 0000 00000000
```

I guess this should tell me that my event is `/dev/input/event6` and I assume that the event codes I need are `0035`, `0036` and `0039`.

So I tried around a little bit and came up with an approach like:

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 935
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6  0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6  0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 57 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6  0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 789
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6  0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6  0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 57 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6  0 0 0
```

This is also done similarly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386449/send-touch-events-to-a-device-via-adb). But it didn't work at all, nothing changed on the device. Since I don't know what to try next or if my approach is correct at all, I'd like to ask you if you could tell me where my mistakes are.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to produce continuous swipe action on the touchscreen, with adb, on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500567/is-it-possible-to-produce-continuous-swipe-action-on-the-touchscreen-with-adb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay - I finally figured out how to do it!

I wrote a little script which converts the `adb shell getevent` to decimal values and replaces the codes with known names from [this article](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html).

That gave me output like this:

```
/dev/input/event6: 3 - TRACKING_ID [4294967295]
/dev/input/event6: 0 - SYN_REPORT [0]
/dev/input/event6: 3 - 47 [0]
/dev/input/event6: 3 - POSITION_X [415]
/dev/input/event6: 3 - POSITION_Y [428]
/dev/input/event6: 3 - TOUCH_MAJOR [5]
/dev/input/event6: 3 - TRACKING_ID [0]
/dev/input/event6: 0 - SYN_REPORT [0]
```

Then I was able to figure out how the events worked and could replicate the behavior. I just needed to change the X and Y coordinates.

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 57 88
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 935
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 48 5
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 906
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 48 16
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 877
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 48 16
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 847
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 48 16
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 818
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 48 16
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 53 789
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 54 500
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 48 16
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 3 57 -1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event6 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is delay between the `sendevent` commands. If you check the `sendevent` source code, It is opening the file each time and write and then close. plus the delay between two `adb shell` commands. This makes continuous sendevent so slow and what you recorded is not getting replicated.

What you have to do is get the `sendevent` [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.0.0_r2/toolbox/sendevent.c), modify it for taking as many as args it can and inside you open file once , parse 3 `int`s at a time and write until all args are parsed, close the file. You can see what you recorded is working like charm.

> default sendevent

```
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 47 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 13578
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330 1
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 325 1
```

> Modified sendevent

```
/data/local/tmp/mysendevent /dev/input/event1 3 47 0 3 57 13578 1 330 1 1 325 1
```

I had done this same sometime  back, you can refer full work here- https://github.com/rils/ARP/wiki

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the timing was not the problem. I still send one command at a time but the order was not correct. See my answer for how it was solved.

Comment: Ok, Nice. From your  example in question I thought the decimal conversion is already taken care.