# Hold and move using adb

Tags: android, adb

Could we simulate the hold and move behavior using adb?

Just like pick a app from the app view and move to specific position on the screen?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25500567/150978

Answer (score 0):

Using [CulebraTester-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) you can touch, hold and swipe. For example, if the drawer is open and there's an icon on `(348, 1530)`, you can drag and drop it on `(348, 400)` on the home screen using this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:9987/v2/uiDevice/swipe' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "segments": [
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y":1530 
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 1300
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 1200
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 1100
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 1000
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 900
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 800
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 700
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 600
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 500
    },
    {
      "x": 348,
      "y": 400
    }
  ],
  "segmentSteps": 50
}'
```

You may need to adapt the coordinates for your case.

Comment: Is there any native adb solution?

Comment: Not that I know of

Answer (score 0):

This can be natively done using

`adb shell input swipe x1 y1 x2 y2 duration`

`tap` is also available as an input option. For a full list, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html