# Pattern unlock using calabash-android

Tags: android, testing, drag, atdd, calabash-android

Part of the Android app I am working on automated testing for has its own pattern unlock component, and I need a way to draw a 'Z' pattern in calabash-android. The pattern is made up of three drag/swipe actions, but they need to be a continuous touch. Currently I can do all three parts of the 'Z' as separate perform_action('drag') commands:

```
perform_action('drag', 17,83,26,26,50)
perform_action('drag', 83,17,26,66,50)
perform_action('drag', 17,83,66,66,50)
```

but I need to be able to do all of that in one go for the test to pass, and I don't know what to do for that. I imagine it has something to do with calabash-androids support for multi-touch gestures, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a pretty solution but you could use a recorded event with adb.  Have a look at this post and see if it helps - [Fire a pinch in/out command to Android phone using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363526/fire-a-pinch-in-out-command-to-android-phone-using-adb/25629952#25629952)