# Android ADB Shell Input - emulate multiple touches

Tags: input, adb

I'm using `adb` Shell input to emulating touchscreen interaction,

Working on Windows 8 with adb command line service.

For one long touch (not tap!) I'm using this command:

> adb shell input swipe x1 y1 x1 y1 t

How can I emulate simultaneous 2 long taps  from command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've searched a bit and seems that the easiest way is not to find the proper commands (you've to emulate a real set of N events moving the 2 fingers around the screen to pinch), but you can instead try this: save a gesture (with X fingers) and then play it back from adb.

For details see this question, already well replied in the Saurabh Meshram answer:

[Fire a pinch in/out command to Android phone using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363526/fire-a-pinch-in-out-command-to-android-phone-using-adb)

---

EDIT:

you can try to understand what the events means (quite obscure at first glimpse), see:
http://ktnr74.blogspot.pt/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

Answer (score -2):

try to use:

> adb shell "input swipe x1 y1 x1 y1 t && input swipe x2 y2 x2 y2 t"

Comment: I've tried, not working as I want, it perform the first command and then the other, not simultaneously.

Comment: I suggest to not delete this answer - it is useful to know, that something *does not* work.