# Want to record touches on my android and play them using adb

Tags: android, adb

I want to be able to record all of the times I touch the screen of my android phone and play it back (without root). Using this  guy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25629952/715439%20%22answer), I managed to record a playback of times I touched my phone using adb.

However, when playing it back, all the touches I made came out immidietly, without waiting for stuff on the phone. For example, if I wanted to enter my app and do some clicking on it, it starts the app, but don't wait for the app to load , just inputs all the touches at once and closes.

I tried recording the touches with `adb shell getevent -t` (using timestamps) but when I tried to play it back I got `use: sendevent device type code value`

I tried using `sleep(2)` after every major touch, and got `/sdcard/sendevent_input.sh[17]: syntax error: '2' unexpected`

I tried using `shell input touchscreen tap x y` and playing it back every few seconds, and I managed to replay two touches, but then for some reason the touches went random (I only recorded records with ABS_MT_POSITION using `adb shell getevent -lt`, and thought the orientation is the problem, so tried using x y, y x, 1080 - x 1920 - y and 1920 - y 1080 -x but all of them didn't work).

All I want is to record my touches with adb (and no root) and play them.

How?

Answer (score 1):

I have made a java application which does the same. This will record and insert delays, and can play back. Save script for alter use as well.This tool whill use a modified `sendevent` to overcome the slowness in playback. 
[Android Record N Play](https://github.com/rils/ARP/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to turn on SHOW TAPS in the developer options.
[image]