# how to execute touch/click in various apps

Tags: java, android, touch

I'm new to Android, but not new to Java, and want for a small project run and click automatically some apps and click around in them.

I don't want to use some screen recording apps, but I'm looking for the method how they emulate touching.

Suddenly I couldn't find anything that sounds right through google, but I may be wrong. Just as a note, my device is already rooted, it is a device just for testing :)

Comment: If you are connected to a PC via adb you can use monkeyrunner: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html Example SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161416/android-monkey-runner-touch-with-move

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that can run by itself  at the end. Like an overlay service that can click around

Comment: If you are looking for an app - this isn't the correct site. If you are writing an app to do it - since you have root - while I haven't tried it - you may want to take a look at: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/nzbIZMG5n3k/V5gY3UIv6ZkJ

Comment: I want to program my own app (if it's an app) to click around on an android devices which is not connected to an computer. I think you link is the same thing what I'm looking for, but there is no actual solution. I know that there are touch recording apps. How do they execute the recorded touch points?

Comment: Unfortunately what you are asking for does require some familiarity with Android - as you state you are 'new' - if you have root you can 'take over' adb in your app and use it like:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32023080/want-to-record-touches-on-my-android-and-play-them-using-adb and inject them in a similar fashion. Android tried to make the device secure for the average user so 'simple' ideas which break that security tend to be not so simple.

Comment: I already suspected that, but I'm not afraid to learn something new :) adb sounds easy but it requires an computer that operates the phone. I don't want that. At the end it should work by itself. Right now I'm just looking for a "basic framework" with which I can work