# Adb shell input drag from a source to a target and keep pressed

Tags: shell, input, adb

I need to simulate this scenario with adb, drag from a srouce point to a target point and keep pressed until an event happens.

how can I write the adb shell command? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways-

**1. Use `getevent` and `sendevent`if coordinates wont change:-**

Record your drag event with `adb shell getevent` and play with `adb shell sendevent`. Refrer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363526/fire-a-pinch-in-out-command-to-android-phone-using-adb/25629952#25629952).

**2. Use uiautomator if drag co-ordinates are not constant**

create a uiautomator jar which accepts your drag coordinates from command line and run via adb shell.