# How to perform "pinch zoom" on a game using ADB via USB for Android

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, adb, pinchzoom

I am developing some automation on a game where I need to use the pinch zoom functionality (for more on multi-touch gestures see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch)).

Solution **possibilities I tried**: Recording events and replaying them, but this is performing very slow through the ADB Shell (for example [this GitHub](https://github.com/Cartucho/android-touch-record-replay)).

That leaves me with my **final question**: How can somebody perform a pinch zoom in/out through a tool/library using Python?

Answer (score 7):

### **First option**

The [uiautomator](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator) by xiaocong. This library specifically supports two point gestures - see examples taken from the GitHub repo:

```
d(text="Settings").gesture((sx1, sy1), (sx2, sy2)) \
              .to((ex1, ey1), (ex2, ey2))
```

*Moving from one point to another with two points.*

Most importantly there is a specific `pinch.in()` and `pinch.out()` function. See:

```
d(text="Settings").pinch.In(percent=100, steps=10)
d(text="Settings").pinch.Out()
```

I can **highly recommend** this python wrapper due to it's detailed documentation as well as the functionality.

First off, install the `uiautomator library`:

```
pip install uiautomator
```

Little code snippet which I used for testing (this only works for Android 4.3 and on-going; *"pinch can not be set until Android 4.3"*):

```
from uiautomator import device as d

#Replace the variables, marked by the percentage signs 
d = Device('%serial_number%', adb_server_host='%server%', adb_server_port=%port%)

#[...]

#Zooming in - arbitrary example values for a "small zoom" in; from the edges to the center
d(text="Settings").pinch.In(percent=30, steps=10)
```

At this point I want to mention a note from the GitHub repo regarding `%server%`:

> Although adb supports `-a` option since SDK 4.3, but now it has a bug on it. The only way to start adb server listenning on all interfaces instead of localhost, is `adb -a -P 5037 fork-server server &`

For further reading on this subject, I highly suggest a question from the Android Stackexchange (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52911/adb-start-server-and-listen-on-all-interfaces).

---

### **Second option**

Doing my research I found another StackOverflow question which is highly related to your post: [Fire a pinch in/out command to Android phone using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363526/fire-a-pinch-in-out-command-to-android-phone-using-adb/25629952#25629952) - Even though this thread isn't specifically for Python, I'd highly suggest taking a look at it. User [@Saurabh Meshram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2968959/saurabh-meshram) described in a detailed manner how to use `getevent` and `sendevent` in order to achieve a pinch in/out motion via adb. *(Further sources: Check out this [blogpost](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/51706817.html) as well)*

Though if I understood your initial question correct, you already tried this approach:

> I have tried recording events

*Still for the sake of completeness the second option should be mentioned.* Anyhow, on to the third option:

---

### **Third option**

Here comes a "tricky" solution. The [python_api](https://github.com/BobbleKeyboard/android_touch/tree/master/python_api) of the [android_touch repo](https://github.com/BobbleKeyboard/android_touch) **doesn't** specifically support a pinch and zoom action per se. Though with the `TouchActionBuilder` you're allowed to construct complex actions as a pinch and zoom.

Depending on the motion you want to have you can combine either the `down()` or `multidown()` option with `move()` and `multimove()`. To achieve this I'd highly suggest taking a look at the [code](https://github.com/BobbleKeyboard/android_touch/blob/master/python_api/touch.py) as well as the example of a "[complex action](https://github.com/BobbleKeyboard/android_touch/tree/master/python_api)".

---

**Further reading and sources**

- https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator
- https://source.android.com/devices/input/getevent
- https://www.iditect.com/how-to/51706817.html
- [Fire a pinch in/out command to Android phone using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363526/fire-a-pinch-in-out-command-to-android-phone-using-adb/25629952#25629952)
- https://github.com/BobbleKeyboard/android_touch
- https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/51706817.html
- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52911/adb-start-server-and-listen-on-all-interfaces
- https://github.com/openstf/minitouch